# Custom formated data in hovertemplate for histogram bins in plotly/dash

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to create a dashboard with dash/plotly to display my daily piano practice time.

The first version of the dashboard should allow me to view how much I practiced each hour/day/week/month.

Binning the data accordingly to the selected time frame is no problem with the examples from plotly's demo.

For now, I always display the amount of time in minutes. However, this does not really work for time spans more than a day, so I'd like to display the amount not as e.g. "117.33 minutes" but as "01:57:19" to be more readable.

[Example of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UaRy.png)

I know that you can display `custom_data` in "normal" bar graphs, but this does not seem to work for histograms, as the `y`-value needs to be calculated per the given `histfunc`. Is there a way to use custom calculated/formated values for the `hovertemplate`, based on the calculated `y`-value for the bin?

This is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd


def serve_layout():
    con = sqlite3.connect('practicetracker.db')
    cur = con.cursor()

    # I'd rather use seconds here
    cur.execute("select started date, seconds/60 minutes FROM practice")
    result = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()

    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['date', 'minutes'])

    data = [dict(
        x=df['date'],
        y=df['minutes'],
        marker=dict(color='rgb(68, 68, 68)'),
        name='date',
        type='histogram',
        histfunc="sum",
        xbins=dict(
            size='1D',
            start='1983-12-31 00:00',
            end='2026-12-31 00:00',
        ),
        hovertemplate=
        '%{y:.2f} minutes practiced<br>' +
        '%{x}<br><extra></extra>'
    )]

    layout = dict(
        paper_bgcolor='rgb(240, 240, 240)',
        plot_bgcolor='rgb(240, 240, 240)',
        title='<b>Minutes practiced</b>',
        bargap=0.2,
        yaxis=dict(
            title='Minutes practiced',
            type='linear'
        ),
        updatemenus=[dict(
            x=0.95,
            y=1,
            xref='paper',
            yref='paper',
            xanchor='left',
            active=1,
            showactive=True,
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    args=['xbins.size', 1000 * 60 * 60],
                    label='Hourly',
                    method='restyle',
                ), dict(
                    args=['xbins.size', 'D1'],
                    label='Day',
                    method='restyle',
                ), dict(
                    args=['xbins.size', 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7],
                    label='Week',
                    method='restyle',
                )]
        )]
    )

    fig_dict = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

    return html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig_dict)
    ])


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = serve_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```